# Calculate Hamming distance between two datasets

Tags: python, numpy, dataframe, scipy, hamming-distance

I need to calculate hamming distance between:

1. My reference dataset of shape N0(rows) x M0(cols) - `Ref.csv`
2. My test dataset of shape N1(rows) x M1(cols) - `Tes.csv`

The resulting matrix should be of shape N0 x N1, which holds the hamming distance between all rows of reference and all rows test (as column in new dataset)

Doing this using a loop could be inefficient.

Some resources I was using

```py
from scipy.spatial.distance import hamming
```

I would ideally want to calculate the hamming distance like shown below, which is computationally less expensive. The loop below calculates Euclidean distance.

```py
def compute_distances_no_loops(Train, X):
    dists = -2 * np.dot(X, Train.T) + np.sum(Train**2,    axis=1) + np.sum(X**2, axis=1)[:, np.newaxis]
    return dists
```

Here are csv datasets on Dropbox you can use: [HammingDistance](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/t00ppj6t3glzxs0/AAD-icT95YioXgBeJYAN0-xja?dl=0)

Comment: do you have the `ground truth/test results` to compare the results with?

Answer (score 0):

Let's start from a notice: **Hamming** distance is computed between
sequences of **equal** length.
Since your both arrays have **different** number of columns, we have
to apply a more general approach, namely **Levenshtein** distance,
taking into account also insertions and deletions.

Although the concept of Levenshtein distance was worked out to compare
strings, it turns out that it can also be applied to sequences of
**numbers**.

I used the following function to compute the Levenshtein distance:

```
def levDist(s1, s2):
    if len(s1) < len(s2): return levDist(s2, s1)
    if len(s2) == 0: return len(s1)
    prev_row = range(len(s2) + 1)
    for i, c1 in enumerate(s1):
        curr_row = [i + 1]
        for j, c2 in enumerate(s2):
            curr_row.append(min(prev_row[j + 1] + 1, curr_row[j] + 1,
                prev_row[j] + (c1 != c2)))
        prev_row = curr_row
    return prev_row[-1]
```

To test my code, I shortened *Tes.csv* and *Res.csv* to first
10 and 4 lines, respectively, and read them:

```
tes = np.loadtxt('Tes.csv', delimiter=',', encoding='utf-8')
ref = np.loadtxt('Ref.csv', delimiter=',', encoding='utf-8')
```

The actual computing is as follows:

```
result = np.zeros([tes.shape[0], ref.shape[0]], dtype=int)
iTes = 0
for tesRow in tes:
    iRef = 0
    for refRow in ref:
        result[iTes, iRef] = levDist(tesRow.tolist(), refRow.tolist())
        iRef += 1
    iTes += 1
```

For your (shrunken) input files, I got the following result:

```
[[ 0 39 38 39]
 [39  4  6  3]
 [39  3  5  0]
 [39  6  8  3]
 [39  3  7  4]
 [39  0  6  3]
 [39  1  5  2]
 [39  3  5  4]
 [39  5  6  4]
 [39  3  3  2]]
```

Comment: Thank you for the thorough explaination, but I just checked the datasets I provided both have 38 columns.

Comment: Even when both sequences are of equal size, you can use my solution anyway. Or replace the call to my function with any other function computing **Hamming** distance.